# Reading TinkerPop library generated files using Spark

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, gremlin, tinkerpop, janusgraph

Is there a direct way of reading tinkerpop format `org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.hadoop.structure.io.ObjectWritable` files using spark.

Spark version: 3.*

Comment: Not an answer, but this might provide some pointers: https://lists.lfaidata.foundation/g/janusgraph-users/topic/79936262